# Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS for IBM POWER8 runs on Openpower servers

Tags: 14.04

I need to know if Ubuntu fr Power 8 runs in Openpower 8 servers like Tyan products.Link below:

http://www.tyan.com/campaign/openpower/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It appears so. IBM has a list of supported features for Ubuntu on POWER8 computers, and I don't see a reason they would have a list if Ubuntu couldn't run on the processor anyway. There is also a question on this site that asks a question about viewing the CPU speeds from Ubuntu on a POWER8 machine. They have it working, so it must be installable.

In short, you really have to just try it out. In most cases, there's no way to tell whether or not it will work, since everyone's experience is at least slightly different. Try it out and see.

[IBM's Feature List](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/linuxonibm/liaam/supportedfeatures_ubuntu.htm?lang=en)

[Question about CPU Speeds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519224/how-can-i-tell-how-fast-the-cpus-are-running-on-a-power8-server)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all version since 14.04 runs on these machines. All the 14.04,X releases are also support. The latest is 14.04.5.

Other than 14.04.X, you can install all the other releases, as 14.10, 15.04, 15.10 and 16.04. 16.10 is still under development, and is also supported on Tyan Power machines.

For more information, please check [Canonical on POWER8](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/power8)

The architecture is named ppc64el, and you can find the images at [Ubuntu 14.04 on POWER8 images](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04/release/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Ubuntu 14.04 (and later) run on all OpenPOWER systems either bare metal or in a VM. I would recommend Ubuntu 16.04 over 14.04 as a lot more packages have been optimized for POWER8. The HWE updates (the 14.04.X) releases are important as they do better support the hardware.

My day job is maintaining the OPAL firmware that runs on these machines. Not a day goes past where I'm not running Ubuntu on a Tyan OpenPOWER machine.